# How can I set the location property of the gecko webbrowser to a point

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

As you know, You can set the location property of most objects through this code

```
    .Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, 60);
```

I could change the location of the webBrowser1 easily and erveything was ok..

but when I tried to use it again to change the location of gecko webBrowser, the location hasn't changed also I didn't get any error message when I used it with gecko webBrowser

```
    geckoWebBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, 60);
```

Also I found this code in a website but in vain nothing has changed.

```
        geckoWebBrowser.Left = (???);
        geckoWebBrowser.Top = (???);
```

Could I know how can I change the location of geckoWebBrowser ??

BTW, I'm running my code `in STA thread (new form)`

Also the version of gecko is `60.55`

Here is my full code

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread threadgec = new System.Threading.Thread(() => rungecko());
        threadgec.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        threadgec.IsBackground = true;
        threadgec.Start();
    }


   
        static void rungecko()
    {

         Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");

        var geckoWebBrowser = new GeckoWebBrowser { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        

         geckoWebBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, 60);


      Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.Controls.Add(geckoWebBrowser);


        geckoWebBrowser.Navigate("www.google.com");

        Application.Run(f);

    }
```

Comment: While using `DockStyle.Fill`, `Control` will `Fit` to its Parent and you can not set `Controls Location`.

For such case use this code `var geckoWebBrowser = new GeckoWebBrowser { Size = new Size(400, 400), Location = new Point(40, 60) };`

Comment: Thank you, How can I Make a tick on your answer?

Comment: Its just comment for your mistake and not an answer.